# How to make a check in the wordpress library: did the user or the function upload the image to the admin panel?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, user-roles

I have the website on `wordpress` and function *replace_uploaded_imag*e in **functions.php** which uploads images from external url and transforms their original sizes to thumbnail sizes.

But I wouldn't like to made this transformations when I directly upload images  in admin library.

What condition do I need to supplement the function or on which hook to hang?

```
function replace_uploaded_image($image_data) {

  if (!isset($image_data['sizes']['thumbnail'])) return $image_data;

  // paths to the uploaded image and the thumbnail image
  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $uploaded_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' .$image_data['file'];

  $current_subdir = substr($image_data['file'],0,strrpos($image_data['file'],"/"));
  $thumbnail_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/'.$current_subdir.'/'.$image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']['file'];

  // delete the uploaded image
  unlink($uploaded_image_location);

  // rename the thumbnail image
  rename($thumbnail_image_location,$uploaded_image_location);

  // update image metadata and return them
  $image_data['width'] = $image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']['width'];
  $image_data['height'] = $image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']['height'];
  unset($image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']);

  return $image_data;
}

add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','replace_uploaded_image');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue first I was need to add second parametr `$attachment_id` to function **replace_uploaded_image** and then find out if *the attachment* has `post_author`.

**Full code:**

```
function replace_uploaded_image($image_data, $attachment_id) {

  // Check if the image was uploaded via the WordPress admin panel
  $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );

  if (isset($attachment->post_author)) {
    return $image_data; // Return the unmodified image data
  }

  // if there is no thumbnail image : return
  if (!isset($image_data['sizes']['thumbnail'])) return $image_data;

  // paths to the uploaded image and the thumbnail image
  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $uploaded_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' .$image_data['file'];
  // $thumbnail_image_location = $upload_dir['path'] . '/'.$image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']['file']; // ** This only works for new image uploads - fixed for older images below.
  $current_subdir = substr($image_data['file'],0,strrpos($image_data['file'],"/"));
  $thumbnail_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/'.$current_subdir.'/'.$image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']['file'];

  // delete the uploaded image
  unlink($uploaded_image_location);

  // rename the thumbnail image
  rename($thumbnail_image_location,$uploaded_image_location);

  // update image metadata and return them
  $image_data['width'] = $image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']['width'];
  $image_data['height'] = $image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']['height'];
  unset($image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']);

  return $image_data;
}

add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','replace_uploaded_image', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition that checks whether the image's metadata contains a post_parent value. This value is only set when an image is uploaded via the admin panel. The post_parent value, the function can determine whether an image was uploaded via the admin panel or not, and only modify images that were uploaded from external URLs.

Here's the modified code:

```
function replace_uploaded_image($image_data) {

  // Check if the image was uploaded via the WordPress admin panel
  if (isset($image_data['post_parent'])) {
    return $image_data; // Return the unmodified image data
  }

  // Continue with the rest of the function if the image was uploaded from an external URL
  if (!isset($image_data['sizes']['thumbnail'])) return $image_data;

  // Rest of the function code
  // ...
}
```

The function will only modify images that were uploaded from external URLs and not via the admin panel.

Comment: thaks for your answer, but it doesn't work for me.. I thied deleted and uploaded images for many times, updated permalinks in the settings, reload page, but averytime new uploaded images appeared with thumbnail size